# How to exactly find shift beween two functions?

Tags: numerics

There is a shift between my numerical and analytical results in my simulation which is not good. However, I need to know exactly how much this shift is. The red line and blue lines are both lists.

[image]

Comment: Please provide executable Mathematica code !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you do not deliver any data, I create 2 datasets using "Exp", the second one is shifted by 2 data points:

```
d1 = Table[Exp[-x^2], {x, -2, 2, .1}];
d2 = Table[Exp[-(x - 0.2)^2], {x, -2, 2, .1}];
ListLinePlot[{d1, d2}]
```

[image: plot of function and shifted equivalent]

Now we calculate the correlation of `d1` and `d2`. That is, we shift `d1` cyclically by 0,1,2... data points and multiply it by `d2`. If we have the right shift, the product will be maximal:

```
cor=ListCorrelate[d1, d2, 1] 
ListLinePlot[cor]
```

[image: a smooth curve with a maximum at 2 and a minimum at 22]

The position of the max will give the shift, where the first position means, no shift, the second position, shift by 1 data point, the third position, shift by 2 data points, ...

```
Position[t, Max[cor]]

(* Out: {{3}} *)
```

Therefore, the shift is 2 data points.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @DanielHuber's answer:

If you consider two functions `f[t],g[t]` (which you please should provide!)

With example form DanielHuber

```
xy1 = Table[{x, Exp[-x^2]}, {x, -2, 2, .1}];
xy2 = Table[{x, Exp[-(x - 0.2)^2]}, {x, -2, 2, .1}];
f = Interpolation[xy1]
g = Interpolation[xy2]

J[shift_] := NIntegrate[(f[t] - g[t - shift])^2, {t, -2, 2}]
NMinimize[J[shift], shift, Method -> "NelderMead"]//Quiet 
{1.58025*10^-9, {shift -> -0.199999}}
```